# Angular 6.1.0 - Restore scroll position not working as expected

Tags: angular

```
RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })
```

This new feature in 6.1.0 doesn't work as expected. It seems that the ViewportScroller service tries to restore the scroll position before the  DOM elements are populated so the max scroll height is essentially the device height. As a result, the scroll position restored is not doing the intended purpose.

I tried doing the following for custom scroll position restoration as suggested by the documentation but to no avail:

```
dataObsevable.pipe(withLatestFrom(scrollEvents)).subscribe(([list, e]) => {
  this.data = list;
  if (e.position) {
    viewPort.scrollToPosition(e.position);
  } else {
    viewPort.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
  }
});
```

The position returned by the piped observable is correctly the value of the scroll position before the page was navigated from. However, it seems viewPort.scrollToPosition() tries to scroll the page before the DOM elements are done initialising so it's doing nothing.

Comment: It's a known issue: https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547. The issue links to examples demonstrating workarounds.

Comment: This issue could be well-resolved if Angular implements data caching on back event or an artificial Angular back event. Would be an even better user experience.

Answer (score 4):

Unfortunately, the [issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547) is still open and I could not get `scrollPositionRestoration` to work properly. [Raphael Balet's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/65255774/11022022) almost did the trick for me, but it seemed like the view was not ready yet when `viewportScroller.scrollToPosition()` was called, even after I made sure it was called after Angular's `ngAfterViewChecked()` lifecycle. Therefore I introduced a delay, which is not a clean solution but it worked:

**app.component.ts**

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Router, Scroll } from '@angular/router';
import { ViewportScroller } from '@angular/common';
import { delay, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

@Component({
  selector: 'root',
  templateUrl: './app.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./app.component.scss'],
})
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    router.events
      .pipe(filter((e): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll))
      .pipe(delay(1))   // <--------------------------- This line
      .subscribe((e) => {
        if (e.position) {
          // backward navigation
          viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
        } else if (e.anchor) {
          // anchor navigation
          viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
        } else {
          // forward navigation
          viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
        }
      });
  }
}
```

For the router module, make sure that `scrollPositionRestoration` is disabled, which is the default value.

**app.router.ts**

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes)],
  exports: [RouterModule],
})
export class AppRoutingModule {}
```

Answer (score 2):

Scroll position restoration

There are two steps involved here,

1. Store the scroll position of the `div`. while navigating to the other page.
2. Assign the stored values to the `div` again when you come back to the page.

if  `RouterModule.forRoot(routes, { scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled' })` does not work, try the following code:

HTML:

Add the following events in the `div` for which you want to restore scroll position

```
(scroll)="onScroll($event)" [scrollTop]="spt" [scrollLeft]="spl"
```

COMPONENT:

```
public spt:any;
public spl:any;

onScroll(event: any) {

sessionStorage.setItem('scroll',JSON.stringify({st:event.srcElement.scrollTop,sl:event.srcElement.scrollLeft}));
    
}

  ngOnInit() {

    if(sessionStorage.getItem('scroll'))
    {    
      //console.log("scrollTop available")
      var sp=JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('scroll'));
      this.spt=sp.st;
      this.spl=sp.sl;
    }

}
```

Comment: I tried to edit the comment, but it seems that the edit queue is full. Could you please wrap all you code between code tags so that it's not displayed as plain text? It can make things pretty confusing to read. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0):

Adding this into you're `app.component.ts` file do the trick.

```js
export class AppComponent {
  constructor(router: Router, viewportScroller: ViewportScroller) {
    router.events.pipe(
      filter((e: Event): e is Scroll => e instanceof Scroll)
    ).subscribe(e => {
      if (e.position) {
        // backward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition(e.position);
      } else if (e.anchor) {
        // anchor navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToAnchor(e.anchor);
      } else {
        // forward navigation
        viewportScroller.scrollToPosition([0, 0]);
      }
    });
  }
}
```

> The reason of this behavior is that page didn't already render and scrollToPosition no have effect.
> There are not a good hack with timeout but it works. [DrDager](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547#issuecomment-630736014)

#### Note

Angular have actually an [open issue](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/24547) regarding this problem

Comment: where is filter() defined? I may be confused with Array.prototype.filter() but clearly this is a different thing