# Restore scroll position not working in angular 10

Tags: angular, angular-material, angular10

```
@NgModule({
  imports: [RouterModule.forRoot(routes, {
    scrollPositionRestoration: 'enabled'
  })],
  exports: [RouterModule]
})
```

When a page scrolled down and taken another new page the new page will show the same position of previous
I tried this code in app-routing.module.ts but it's not working.. any solution ?

Comment: See this https://stackoverflow.com/questions/51572675/angular-6-1-0-restore-scroll-position-not-working-as-expected